# call dict iterator function for each member in dict

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, iterator

I want to execute some function for each item from dictionary/List. I tried doing this but its not giving expected results. Here is the code.

```
class GroupDict(dict):
def iteritems(self):
    # do some operation for every member in dict
    print "in __iter__"
    return super(GroupDict, self).iteritems()
a = GroupDict()
a['a'] = 0
a['b'] = 1
for key in a.iteritems():
    print key
```

for this I am getting output

`in __iter__
('a', 0)
('b', 1)`

But expected is

`in __iter__
('a', 0)
in __iter__
('b', 1)`

I don't want to do operation inside the for loop but whatever I mention in the class should be executed for every member. Please help me with this.

Comment: Why in the world would you inherit form dict and override `iteritems` to achieve this? Just `for k,v in a.iteritems(): f(k, v)` for whatever function `f` you want. What is wrong with doing the operation in the for-loop?

Comment: I cant add this code inside for loop partly because of the way code is structured and secondly I have to change lot of things if gone by that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iteritems()` only gets called once, before the loop actually starts.

Let's see why.  This loop:

```
for x in EXP:
    do_something()
```

Roughly translates to:

```
it = iter(EXP)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    do_something()
```

If you want to do something for every member, it is easier to do what you want by `yield`ing from `iteritems()`:

```
def iteritems(self):
    for k, v in super(GroupDict, self).iteritems():
        print "doing something with %s / %s" % (k,v)
        yield k, v
```

Comment: tried wrapping __iter__ method as well but this is also called only once. So which method do you mean by dict-iterator?

Comment: @ShriShinde yes, you need to override `next` (in Python 2, `__next__` in Python 3).

Comment: @ShriShinde you need to define your own *iterator class*, and do whatever you want in its `__next__()` method (`next()` in python2), and override `iteritems()` to return your own iterator.  A simpler option is to make `iteritems()` a generator, by using `yield`. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: @shx2 yes, overriding `iteritems` with a generator is probably the easiest way to go.